# How do I come to know that project on git get modified using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit to maintain version of project.
But on other machine I created repository and just want to keep it up to date with all modification done by developer.
How do I can get that using TortoiseGit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-pull.html

Comment: Before pull ,is it possible to know that there is modification happen on file .

Comment: Then, using fetch. Perhaps [ProGit - Remote Branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) help.

Comment: Before pull, you can use command line: `git fetch origin --dry-run`